# Using a cookie to remember background color and present it on access from a form

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

Hi everyone I have created my code so that once a user fills out a form and presses submit it will remember the preferences from that form using a cookie.

My first problem is that I can't get i don't know how to use an "init()" method to print a message to the user.

My second problem is that when the user comes back on the same page I have no idea on how to display the page according to the form the user filled in. (if someone clicked blue for the background once it comes back to page to be still displayed in blue). I have tried in doing so by remembering the first name and the changing the color according to their selection.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
            function changeColour(buttonColour){
                if (buttonColour =="red"){
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
                    document.body.style.color = "#CCFFFF";
                }else if(buttonColour == "blue"){
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF";
                    document.body.style.color = "#CCFFFF";

                }else if(buttonColour == "green"){
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#009933";
                    document.body.style.color = "#CCFFFF";
                }
            }


            expirydate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+numdays);
            expirydate.toUTCString();

            function setCookie(firstname){
                var expirydate = new Date();
                document.cookie = "firstname =" + encodeURIComponent(firstname);
                expirydate.setDate(expirydate.getDate()+ 7*24*60*60*1000);
                expirydate.toUTCString();

                var checkedbox;
                elementArray = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                console.log(elementArray);


                for (var i =0; i<elementArray.length; i++){
                    if(elementArray[i].type="radio" && elementArray[i].checked){
                        checkedbox = elementArray[i].value;
                        alert(checkedbox);
                        document.cookie = "buttonColour" + "=" +  encodeURIComponent(checkedbox);
                    }
                }           
            }

            function readCookie(firstname){
                var namevalueArray = document.cookie.split(";");


                for(var i =0; i< namevalueArray.length; i++){
                    var smallvalueArray = namevalueArray[i].trim().split("=");  
                        if(smallvalueArray[0]== firstname){
                            document.cookie = "firstname" + decodeURIComponent(firstname);
                            return smallvalueArray[1];
                        }else{
                            return null;
                    }
                }

                function init(){
                    print("welcome =", firstname)
                }

            }





        </script>
        <script type="text/css">
            #formsa{
                width:300px;
                height:400px;
                position: absolute;
                font-weight: bolder;
                left:200px;
                top:70px;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload=init()>
        <div id="formsa">
        <form name="test" method="get" id="forms">      
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
        Red colour: <input type="radio" name="buttonColour" value="red" onchange=
"changeColour('red');"><br>
        Green colour: <input type="radio" name="buttonColour" value="green" onchange=
"changeColour('green');"><br>
        Blue colour: <input type="radio" name="buttonColour" value="blue" onchange=
"changeColour('blue');"><br>
        <button type="button" value="Save" id="saveButton" onclick=`enter code here`
"setCookie(firstname.value);">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure I really follow what you are trying to do but I'll attempt to give you some pointers...

1. When the page loads you can use your `init` function as you are doing it now
2. In the `init` function if you want to "print" a message on the user's face, then you have two options...

   a. Render the "welcome" message on the page by setting the `innerHTML` property of an html element such as a heading...`h1`, `h2`, `h3`, etc
   b. By "alerting" the message, I personally don't like this approach, but it is another option using the `alert` function instead of whatever you are doing with `print`, because `print` doesn't seem to be defined in your code unless you are trying to print to a printer...which I doubt, either way that's not the correct way to launch the Print Dialogue of the browser
3. In the `init` function you should attempt to retrieve the cookie in a safe way
4. If the cookie exists, retrieve its values and set the html elements accordingly
5. If it doesn't exist, render the page as you normally would

You already have most of the logic written to read/write cookies and read/write to html elements. It's just a matter of implementing them in your `init` function

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I didn't want to use an alert so innerHTML is right for me. My other problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the cookie and then allow the page to be rendered as the user wanted. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: But, you are already doing that in your code...just make sure you set the cookie name, the value(s) and the expiration and you'll be good to go